# How can I pass Getopt::Long options to a subroutine that's also an option?

Tags: perl, config, subroutine, getopt-long

I am trying to setup `Getopt::Long` to handle the arguments from a configuration script.

Here is my starter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $config_file = '';

GetOptions (    
    'config|c=s' => \$config_file,
    'add|a' => \&add_server,
    'del|d' => \&del_server,        
);

sub add_server {    
    print "$config_file\n";    
}

sub del_server {    
    # Left blank for now.    
}
```

The odd thing is I am running into a problem when I run my script with something like this:

`./config.pl -a -c config.xml`

It does NOT print the `-c` option, but if I run it like this,

`./config.pl -c config.xml -a`

it works like it should.

I think I understand the reason why; it has to do with the order execution right?

How can I fix it? Should I use `Getopt::Long` in conjunction with `@ARGV`?

Ultimately, I am trying to make the command line args pass into the subroutine that I am calling. So if `-a` or `--add`, I want the options of `-c` or `--config` to pass into the subroutine when it is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the need to call the subroutine directly from the `GetOptions` call.  Control the order like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my %opts = (config => '');

GetOptions(\%opts, qw(
   config|c=s
   add|a
   del|d
));

add_server() if $opts{add};
del_server() if $opts{del};

sub add_server {    
    print "$opts{config}\n";
}

sub del_server {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boiling the example down a little bit...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $config_file = '';

GetOptions (

    'config|c=s' => \$config_file,
    'add|a' => sub{add_server($config_file);}
);

sub add_server
{

    my $config=shift;

    if(defined($config))
    {
        print "Got this for a config file: $config\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "No argument supplied to add_server\n";
    }

}
```

... and running `config.pl -c blurg -a` returns the output `Got this for a config file: blurg`, and running `config.pl -a -c blurg` returns `Got this for a config file:`.

So, what I suspect is happening is that the options are assigned in the order given.  So in the first case `$config_file` is assigned to the `-c` argument and then the `add_server` subroutine is called (with the correct argument), whereas in the second case, `add_server` is immediately fired off with no argument and then `$config_file` is assigned.

All this aside, I'd recommend making `-a` a boolean and do whatever you want to do if it's enabled (and if an argument for `-c` is supplied).

Comment: Re: "you can't associate an option directly to a code-reference to a named subroutine." Completely false. A code ref is a code ref.

Comment: @ikegami - Upon further reading, it looks as though that's only for the exportable messages.  Lemme edit.

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks are called as the options are encountered, so `add_server` is being called before `-c` has been encountered when you do

```
./config.pl -a -c config.xml
```

Based on the latest info, you now want:

```
use Getopt::Long qw( GetOptions );

GetOptions(
   'a=s' => \my $opt_a,
   'd=s' => \my $opt_d,
   'h=s' => \my $opt_h,
   'p=s' => \my $opt_p,
) or usage();
```

Comment: I only need to specify a single config file.

Comment: @Solignis, Why not just do `-a config.xml`, then?

Comment: @Solignis, Why don't you specify what interface you do want before this becomes a game of 20 questions.

Comment: The original idea was to have `-a` and `-d` control the specific section of the config you wish to add or delete. For example `-a server01` would call the `add_server` subroutine with the option `server01` But I could not figure out how to get one option to do two things without getting messy.

Comment: @Solignis, Q2) Which option should do two things? Q3) What two things should it do?

Comment: @Solignis, I forgot to mention that I updated based on your last message. Still had to make many guesses due to the lack of spec.

Comment: When you mean lack of spec what do you need to know. I am sorta of creating this "on the fly" and just trying to shape out something. The basic idea is I am trying to make a small script that creates a config file for another program. I want the script to take inputs for the mode `-a, -d` (for now) and inputs for the options like `-h for host` `-p for port` etc.. The biggest thing I am trying to accompish is something that has lots of "safety" so when it encounters and invalid option it stops instead of moving on which is what does with everything I tried. Follow me?

Comment: @Solignis, Wow, you didn't say any of this before!!! Post updated for lastest spec. Except for the moving on part. Using GetOptions to get behaviour other than GetOptions is not gonna work.

Comment: So if I trying to use GetOptions in the wrong way then what would be a better method? Use @ARGV to capture the primary mode I wish to run then use GetOptions to capture the options like $config_file?

Comment: @Solignis, I would recommend removing the requirement that some errors should be kept hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the [pass_through](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Configuring-Getopt%3a%3aLong) option on Getopt::Long so that it will ignore unknown options, then call GetOptions once for your options, disable it again, and then use GetOptions again for your command.

Answer (score -2):

```
GetOptions(
        'arg=s' => sub { print "$_[1]\n"; },
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would be self explaning. The `GetOptions()` function passes the parameters array `@_` to the whatever_you_like function that is referenced as argument action. The array contains the full name of the argument (`arg`) in $_[0] and it's value in $_[1].